# DateTime in Safari and Chrome Render different with .ToJSON

Tags: javascript, datetime

Within our application we are trying to pass through a users selected datetime of which is causing issues within different browsers.
As an example, running the below in both Chrome, and Safari both output a different time. Chrome honours the BST and yet safari does not

```
new Date('2020-08-11T11:47:00').toJSON()
```

Have tried to google, but unable to find any specific examples for this.

Are there any solutions in place to get around this issue?

EDIT

Chrome output :-
"2020-08-11T10:47:00.000Z"

Safari output :-
"2020-08-11T11:47:00.000Z"

Comment: What output do they give?

Comment: @evolutionxbox i have just added the samples to the question. Thank you

Comment: All browsers on my computer give `"2020-08-11T11:47:00.000Z"`. Safari, Chrome, Firefox, all on macOS

Comment: Is the output from Safari consistent with the result of `.toISOString()` on Safari?

Comment: @Pointy tried in both browsers with .toISOString(). with the same issue.

Comment: Maybe the browsers are set-up at different time zones. Just a guess

Comment: What if your source date string has the explicit "Z" at the end instead of relying on the default?

Comment: @Prasanna, thank you. ive check, Its a brand new mac book, everything is the same.  A colleague has also tested, and getting the same issue

Comment: What versions of the browsers? OSes?

Comment: @Pointy THANK YOU!!    i think the 'Z' on the input date has resolved it..  it has altered the chrome date.   Thank you everyone

Answer (score 0):

Safari's parser is buggy. '2020-08-11T11:47:00' *should* be parsed as local, but Safari (up to v 13.1.2 at least) treats it as UTC. Don't use the built–in parser, see [*Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results)